# BaseEntity Property class .net

Tags: c#, entity

I am trying to create **base entity class for Update and Delete** for **all** classes.

I created **class** and **interfaces** below (Do not know correct or not)

**Entity Class (This is my base entity class)**

```
  public class Entity 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? CreatorId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }



        public List<Delete> DeletedUser { get; set; }
        public List<Update> UpdatedUser { get; set; } 
    }
```

**Delete Interface**

```
public interface Delete
    {
        int? DeletedId { get; set; }
        DateTime? DeletedTime { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update Interface**

```
public class Update
    {
        public int? UpdatedId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedTime { get; set; }
    }
```

If i set object below and use UpdatedUser and DeletedUser can not reach DeletedId,DeletedTime or UpdatedId,UpdatedTime

**ActionResult**

```
 BaseEntity.Entity baseEntity = new BaseEntity.Entity();


  baseEntity.UpdatedUser. (UpdatedId) can not reach here
```

Updated user and Deleted User can be multiple however i can not reach from baseEntity.UpdatedUser. or baseEntity.DeletedUser.

How can i create baseentity class in order to use **OOP** in .net?

Comment: `UpdatedUser` is a `List<Update>`, it does not have a `UpdatedId` property, each item in the list has the property so if you want to "reach" it then you need to access a specific item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

They are not single objects, they are lists. When you have a list and you try to access a property of single object on that list, it doesn't make any sense. If you wanna access properties of a user, then get the user you want first then you can access it's properties.